# minio-py return 'version_id' = None while fput_object

Tags: python, storage, bucket, minio

When I updated version of Minio to '2023-01-20T02:05:44Z' I saw that fput_object return 'version_id' = None sometimes.

When it happens:

1. Many fput_object in one bucket.
2. Transfer large files with fput_object

```py
    minio_obj = minio_client.fput_object(
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        object_name= object_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

By default, fput_object calc part_size (parameter for deviding data by chunks for transfering) by [formula](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/039ff29d76a45427498d04153ddc74776f5d777f/minio/helpers.py#L131-L134).

And for all files with size < 49 Gb part_size=5Mb.

When I set this size to 50Mb (calculated by my own tests) the problem is gone.

```py
client.fput_object(
    bucket_name=bucket_name,
    object_name= name,
    part_size=50*1024*1024)
```